# Connect azure runbook with file share in azure with python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-files, azure-runbook

I have azure automation runbook script that I want to connect to a file share in azure. I can't acess the file share with the runbook, I tried the code bellow, but it didn't work.

```
conn_str = ''
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)

blob_list = blob_service_client.get_container_client('').list_blobs()

for blob in blob_list:
    print(blob.name)
```

How can I get acess of the files in the file share, with a runbook in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to achieve what I wanted with the help of this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=python#enumerate-files-and-directories-in-an-azure-file-share

And I used this example code:

```
file_service = FileService(account_name='', account_key='')
generator = file_service.list_directories_and_files('')
for file_or_dir in generator:
    print(file_or_dir.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage Azure blob with python3 in Azure runbook, we need to import package `azure.storage.blob` with its dependencies.

**Step 1:**
***a) Download this package:***

```
pip3 download -d <output dir name> azure-storage-blob==12.8.0
```

***b) Import these packages***
[image]

**Step 2:**

***Runbook - connect code***

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connect_str = ''
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client('test')
blobs = container_client.list_blobs( )
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

***Test and Output:***

[image]

Comment: when you say: .get_container_client('test') being 'test' the name of the container right?

Comment: Hi @Sofia,     `container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client('test')`
    
  Here `get_container_client(container)` - Gets a client to interact with the specified container.
  Here (`container`) is a parameter which can be either be the ***name of the container***, or an ***instance*** of ContainerProperties. For more information, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python#get-container-client-container-)

Comment: but can we consider azure file share a container?

Comment: @Sofia, No! Container is like a folder/directory and File share is like local disk or public share path

Comment: So, in that case, since Im working with file share, this code doesn't work right?

Comment: Hi @Sofia, did you worked on the above code and process flow?

Comment: yes I worked the code above, but it doesn't work because it refers to a blob storage. However I manage to achieve what I wanted, please check the answer to my question. And thank you for the help and patience.